# Python 3 print([1, 2] and 3) outputs 3

Tags: python-3.x, printing, boolean, operators

I typed

```
print([1,2] and 3)
```

and the result is

```
3
```

How did this happen? Why is the result `3`?

I guess `[1,2]` is considered as `True`. But I don't know how the backend process works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Boolean Operations — and, or, not

These are the Boolean operations, ordered by ascending priority:

| Operation | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x or y | if x is false, then y, else x | (1) |
| x and y | if x is false, then x, else y | (2) |
| not x | if x is false, then True, else False | (3) |

Notes:

1. This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.
2. This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is true.
3. not has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so not a == b is interpreted as not (a == b), and a == not b is a syntax error.

[Please check this official python doc for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 2):

When Boolean "and" operator is "True" it return the last/left most "True" value in expression.

```
>>> print(3 and 5)
5
>>> print((3 and [1,4] and [1,2] ))
[1, 2]
```

Boolean operator give "False" for 0, when "and" operator result is "False" it return the firstly "False" value in expression.

```
>>> print([1,2] and 0)
0

>>> z = False 
>>> print((3 and z and 0 ))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

[This Article From Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-the-and-and-or-operators-work-in-Python) says it best:

> Python uses `and` and `or` operators in a slightly different way.
>
> It doesn’t return pure boolean values (i.e. `True` or `False`) as someone
> working with a language like Java might expect.
>
> It returns one of the operand based on conditions, and the truth value
> of that operand determines the boolean value if used in a conditional
> statement.
>
> `and`:
> Return the first Falsy value if there are any, else return the last
> value in the expression.
>
> `or`:
> Return the first Truthy value if there are any, else return the last
> value in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

`and` is a Boolean Operator.

It returns the first operand that evaluates to `False` or the last one if all evaluate to `True`.
In this case it will return `3`. If the list was empty it would return the empty list, as you can see in this example:

```
>>> [] and 3
[]
```